# Haskell profiling for a fixed amount of time

Tags: haskell, profiling

I am currently trying to profile a Haskell server. The server runs forever, so I just want a profiling report for a fixed amount of time. I tried just running the program for 3 minutes, and then politely ask it to terminate, but somehow the haskell profiler doesn't obey the term signal, and generates incomplete data.

My first attempt:

```
timeout --signal SIGTERM 3m ./actionsDemo +RTC -hc -RTS -p -K100M
```

Anyone any idea how to neatly profile this server?

Comment: I believe that any 'request' to terminate the haskell runtime will lead to the profiler not writing all of its data to disk. Can you fork a thread that will wait for 3 minutes and then close your program from within? Your listener just needs to perform an additional check for some global flag.

Comment: I thank you for your suggestion, but would rather not edit the code I am profiling :)

Comment: Are you interested in `-p` profiling, heap profiling, or both?

Comment: mostly heapprofiling, I want to know what changing some string code was to the heap.

Answer (score 2):

The methods for getting a heap profile of a running program are well documented [here](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.1/html/users_guide/hp2ps.html), section 5.5.3. In short, you just need to remove the last "incomplete" sample, and then proceed as usual.

There's also a relevant [trac ticket](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7291) to make hp2ps handle this on its own, but it doesn't seem to be ready yet.

For time/allocation profiling, I don't have an answer.

Comment: Yes, that was something I figured as well, but unfortunally it doesnt solve the problem, when I use the above command and remove the incomplete line it only stores ~6 seconds, instead of 3 minutes minus a sample.

Comment: That's strange. Have you tried manually editing the .hp file? It works for me.

Comment: Maybe you can post a link to the file? When I run the `-hc` profile, my file has entries every tenth of a second, by default.

Comment: Tested that today, I run the script for 3 minutes, but got only ~54 lines of output, so it doesnt really store all of the data minus a sample ( https://gist.github.com/windwarrior/32885ad1b0d3abb4a61b). still running with the same command but without the -p

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the timeout inside the Haskell code instead, e.g. by wrapping everything in the [`System.Timeout.timeout`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/System-Timeout.html) function. That way the runtime should have a better chance to respond and give a proper profile.

```hs
import System.Timeout (timeout)

main = timeout (3*60*1000000) $ do
  ...
```